# Multiple force-layout graphs with d3 in seperate svg/div's

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I've a problem with creating multiple force layout graphs using d3 and reading data from a json file. I use a for loop to iterate over the graphs, create a separate div containing a svg for each. The problem is, that the force layout is only applied to the last one created, so basically the others just show a dot in the upper left corner. I could solve it partly by putting a for loop at the end of each iteration, but I still lose the interaction capabilities of the separate figures.

Find the code below, thanks in advance.

Cheers, Michael

```
var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = new Array();
var div = new Array();
var svg = new Array();
var graph = new Array();
var link;
var node;
var width = 360;
var height = 360;
var brush = new Array();
var shiftKey;
var count = 0;

//loop through the different subsystems in the json-file
for(name_subsystem in graphs) {
    //add a div for each subsystem
    div[count] = document.createElement("div");
    div[count].style.width = "360px";
    div[count].style.height = "360px";
    div[count].style.cssFloat="left";
    div[count].id = name_subsystem;

    document.body.appendChild(div[count]);


    //force is called. all attributes with default values are noted. see API reference on github.
    force[count] = d3.layout.force()
        .size([width, height])
        .linkDistance(20)
        .linkStrength(1)
        .friction(0.9)
        .charge(-30)
        .theta(0.8)
        .gravity(0.1);

    div[count].appendChild(document.createTextNode(name_subsystem));

    //create the svg rectangle in which other elements can be visualised
    svg[count] = d3.select("#"+name_subsystem)
        .on("keydown.brush", keydown)
        .on("keyup.brush", keyup)
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("id",name_subsystem);

    brush[count] = svg[count].append("g")
        .datum(function() { return {selected: false, previouslySelected: false}; })
        .attr("class", "brush");

    //force is started
    force[count]
        .nodes(graphs[name_subsystem].nodes)
        .links(graphs[name_subsystem].links)
        .start();

    //link elements are called, joined with the data, and links are created for each link object in links
    link = svg[count].selectAll(".link")
        .data(graphs[name_subsystem].links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.thickness); })
        .style("stroke", function(d){
            if (d.linktype === 'reactant'){
                return "black";
            } else {
                return "red";
            }
        });

    //node elements are called, joined with the data, and circles are created for each node object in nodes
    node = svg[count].selectAll(".node")
        .data(graphs[name_subsystem].nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        //radius
        .attr("r", 5)
        //fill
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.type === 'metabolite') {
                return "blue";
            } else {
                return "red";
            }
        })
        .on("mousedown", function(d) {
            if (!d.selected) { // Don't deselect on shift-drag.
                if (!shiftKey) node.classed("selected", function(p) { return p.selected = d === p; });
            else d3.select(this).classed("selected", d.selected = true);
            }
        })
        .on("mouseup", function(d) {
            if (d.selected && shiftKey) d3.select(this).classed("selected", d.selected = false);
        })
        .call(force[count].drag()
            .on("dragstart",function dragstart(d){
                d.fixed=true;
                d3.select(this).classed("fixed",true);
            })
        );


    //gives titles to nodes. i do not know why this is separated from the first node calling.
    node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    //enable brushing of the network
    brush[count].call(d3.svg.brush()
        .x(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, width]))
        .y(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, height]))
        .on("brushstart", function(d) {
            node.each(function(d) { d.previouslySelected = shiftKey && d.selected; });
        })
        .on("brush", function() {
            var extent = d3.event.target.extent();
            node.classed("selected", function(d) {
                return d.selected = d.previouslySelected ^
                (extent[0][0] <= d.x && d.x < extent[1][0]
                && extent[0][1] <= d.y && d.y < extent[1][1]);
            });
        })
        .on("brushend", function() {
            d3.event.target.clear();
            d3.select(this).call(d3.event.target);
        })
    );

    //applies force per step or 'tick'. 
    force[count].on("tick", function() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    });
    //with this it works partly
    //for (var i = 0; i < 5000; ++i)force[count].tick();
    count++;
};

function keydown() {
  if (!d3.event.metaKey) switch (d3.event.keyCode) {
    case 38: nudge( 0, -1); break; // UP
    case 40: nudge( 0, +1); break; // DOWN
    case 37: nudge(-1,  0); break; // LEFT
    case 39: nudge(+1,  0); break; // RIGHT
  }
  shiftKey = d3.event.shiftKey || d3.event.metaKey;
}

function keyup() {
  shiftKey = d3.event.shiftKey || d3.event.metaKey;
}
```

edit: updated the code after the comments, still the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the code I finally used with the help of the comments above, maybe helpful for others as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3_splitted_var.json"></script>
<script>
function draw_graphs(name_subsystem){   

    var force;
    var div;
    var svg;
    var link;
    var node;
    var width = 360;
    var height = 360;
    var r=5;
    var brush = new Array();
    var shiftKey;

    //add a div for each subsystem
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = "360px";
    div.style.height = "360px";
    div.style.cssFloat="left";
    div.id = name_subsystem;

    document.body.appendChild(div);

    force = d3.layout.force()
        .size([width, height])
        .linkDistance(20)
        .linkStrength(1)
        .friction(0.9)
        .charge(-50)
        .theta(0.8)
        .gravity(0.1);

    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name_subsystem));

    //create the svg rectangle in which other elements can be visualised
    svg = d3.select("#"+name_subsystem)
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("id",name_subsystem);

    //force is started
    force
            .nodes(graphs[name_subsystem].nodes)
        .links(graphs[name_subsystem].links)
        .start();

    //link elements are called, joined with the data, and links are created for each link object in links
    link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(graphs[name_subsystem].links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.thickness); })
        .style("stroke", function(d){
            if (d.linktype === 'reactant'){
                return "black";
            } else {
                return "red";
            }
        });

    //node elements are called, joined with the data, and circles are created for each node object in nodes
    node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(graphs[name_subsystem].nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        //radius
        .attr("r", r)
        //fill
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.type === 'metabolite') {
                return "blue";
            } else {
                return "red";
            }
        })
        .call(force.drag()
            .on("dragstart",function dragstart(d){
                d.fixed=true;
                d3.select(this).classed("fixed",true);
            })
        );

    //gives titles to nodes. i do not know why this is separated from the first node calling.
    node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });


    //applies force per step or 'tick'.
    force.on("tick", function() {
        node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(r, Math.min(width - r, d.x)); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(r, Math.min(height - r, d.y)); });

        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    });
};
for(name_subsystem in graphs) {
    draw_graphs(name_subsystem);
}
</script>
```

Note: graphs is the name of the variable in my json file. You need to include the d3-library.

Answer (score 4):

i am working on force layout only, with many graphs at same time.

1 You don't need to have a count variable for each graph.

2 Don't make these variable(force, svg, graph) as array. There is no need for it. just declare them above as (var svg;) and further on. As you call the function, it automatically makes its different copy and DOM maintain them separately. So every variable you are using in graph, make it declare on top of function.

3 You are drawing all the graphs at same time, so as the new one is called, the previous one stops from being making on svg, that's why only last graph built successfully. So draw them after small time intervals.

```
<html>
<script>
function draw_graphs(graphs){

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force;
var div;
var svg;
var graph;
var link;
var node;
var width = 360;
var height = 360;
var brush = new Array();
var shiftKey;


//loop through the different subsystems in the json-file
for(name_subsystem in graphs) {
//add a div for each subsystem
div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "360px";
div.style.height = "360px";
div.style.cssFloat="left";
div.id = name_subsystem;

document.body.appendChild(div); 


//force is called. all attributes with default values are noted. see API reference on github.
force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(20)
    .linkStrength(1)
    .friction(0.9)
    .charge(-30)
    .theta(0.8)
    .gravity(0.1);

div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name_subsystem));

//create the svg rectangle in which other elements can be visualised
svg = d3.select("#"+name_subsystem)
    .on("keydown.brush", keydown)
    .on("keyup.brush", keyup)
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("id",name_subsystem); 

brush = svg.append("g")
    .datum(function() { return {selected: false, previouslySelected: false}; })
    .attr("class", "brush"); 

//force is started
force
    .nodes(graphs[name_subsystem].nodes)
    .links(graphs[name_subsystem].links)
    .start();

//link elements are called, joined with the data, and links are created for each link object in links
link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graphs[name_subsystem].links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.thickness); })
    .style("stroke", function(d){
        if (d.linktype === 'reactant'){
            return "black";
        } else {
            return "red";
        }
    });

//node elements are called, joined with the data, and circles are created for each node object in nodes
node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graphs[name_subsystem].nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    //radius
    .attr("r", 5)
    //fill
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.type === 'metabolite') {
            return "blue";
        } else {
            return "red";
        }
    })
    .on("mousedown", function(d) {
        if (!d.selected) { // Don't deselect on shift-drag.
            if (!shiftKey) node.classed("selected", function(p) { return p.selected = d === p; });
        else d3.select(this).classed("selected", d.selected = true);
        }
    })
    .on("mouseup", function(d) {
        if (d.selected && shiftKey) d3.select(this).classed("selected", d.selected = false);
    })
    .call(force.drag()
        .on("dragstart",function dragstart(d){
            d.fixed=true;
            d3.select(this).classed("fixed",true);
        })
    );


//gives titles to nodes. i do not know why this is separated from the first node calling.
node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

//enable brushing of the network
brush.call(d3.svg.brush()
    .x(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, width]))
    .y(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, height]))
    .on("brushstart", function(d) {
        node.each(function(d) { d.previouslySelected = shiftKey && d.selected; });
    })
    .on("brush", function() {
        var extent = d3.event.target.extent();
        node.classed("selected", function(d) {
            return d.selected = d.previouslySelected ^
            (extent[0][0] <= d.x && d.x < extent[1][0]
            && extent[0][1] <= d.y && d.y < extent[1][1]);
        });
    })
    .on("brushend", function() {
        d3.event.target.clear();
        d3.select(this).call(d3.event.target);
    })
);

//applies force per step or 'tick'. 
force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
//with this it works partly
//for (var i = 0; i < 5000; ++i)force[count].tick();
};

function keydown() {
if (!d3.event.metaKey) switch (d3.event.keyCode) {
case 38: nudge( 0, -1); break; // UP
case 40: nudge( 0, +1); break; // DOWN
case 37: nudge(-1,  0); break; // LEFT
case 39: nudge(+1,  0); break; // RIGHT
}
shiftKey = d3.event.shiftKey || d3.event.metaKey;
}

function keyup() {
shiftKey = d3.event.shiftKey || d3.event.metaKey;
}

}
</script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
draw_graphs("pass here the json file");


// this will drawn 2nd graph after 1 second.              
var t = setTimeout(function(){
draw_graphs("pass here json file");
}, 1000)

});
```

Comment: The count variable was mainly to distinguish the div-containers. The arrays were mainly a try because I thought it might help if the variables are known outside of the function, but I got rid of that now.

Comment: For the third point, that's the main issue. Is it possible to keep the svg's "active" when a new one is called. For the generation a small time interval is fine, but I would like to have the option of dragging the nodes afterwards. Is that possible at all?

Comment: you can append graphs on same div, or you can pass the div id to function on which you want to draw graph.

Comment: after the successful creation of graphs, they will behave independently because DOM will make them different. So there will no issue regarding that.

Comment: just remember one thing that, all variables you are using in function, make them declare on top, so that always a new copy for them will be generated whenever the function is called.

Comment: I see why the graphs behave independently (and I want them to) but the problem is, I can only modify the one created last.
Appending to the same div and declaring the variables on top doesn't help with that, but I changed that now.

Comment: what type of modification you are doing? if it is on click event, then it works for graph you are clicking by itself, but if you are doing automatic modification, then you have to maintain some type of variable for it.

Comment: I'd like to be able to drag the nodes. When I click on one of the graphs it doesn't get modified at all, or do I need to include a separate function to handle the click event? I thought this is done by the drag function.

Comment: the one big error in your function is that you are declaring the count variable inside the function only, so as you call the function, always a new copy will be made for count variable and the same force with zero index get replaced. So correct this in your code. Second thing, i had told you that there is no need for count, it always make new copy, just declare you variables on top in your function, not outside them.

Comment: I updated the code in the original question now. I got rid of the function completely, but still I can only modify the last svg. In the meantime I added some other code for brushing and dragging nodes, but that works fine (in the last graph). Note that the variable graphs is loaded beforehand.

Comment: I have updated your code and here is the link for it http://pastebin.com/ARW2t1Cv . Pass the json file name or path to the function, it will draw the graph for it. Chnage some namesystem you had taken, as you need it

Comment: I tried your code, but I get the error:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` Do I need to include another library?