# Mutiple force layouts in multiple svg in single page not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to implement two force layouts in single page in two different SVGs. I have created to different objects for below function.

```
//object for handling 
var forceGraph = function(){


var force = d3.layout.force();

var width,height,vis;
var nodes = force.nodes();
var links = force.links();
this.disNodes = nodes;
this.disLinks = links;
var removedNodes = [];
var removedLinks = [];
var newNodes=[],newLinks=[];

this.setWidth = function(w){
    width = w;
}
this.setHeight = function(h){
    height = h;
}
this.setCanvas = function(c){
    vis = c;
}
//adds new node to force.nodes of not existing in force.nodes
this.addNode = function(id){
    if(!isNodeExisting(id)){
        nodes.push({'id':id,'type':'circle'});
        this.update();
    }
}
//adds new square node to force.nodes
this.addSquareNode = function(id){
    if(!isNodeExisting(id)){
        nodes.push({'id':id,'type':'rect'});
        this.update();
    }
}

//remove extra nodes from force.nodes
this.removeNodes = function(switches,hosts){
    var obj = this;
    for(i=nodes.length-1;i>-1;i--){
            if(switches.indexOf(nodes[i].id)==-1 && hosts.indexOf(nodes[i].id)==-1){
                removedNodes.push(nodes[i]);
                nodes.splice(i,1);
                obj.update();
            }
        }
}
//removes extra links from force.links
this.removeLinks = function(){
    var obj = this;
    $.each(removedNodes,function(i,val){
        for(i=links.length-1;i>-1;i--){
            if(links[i].source.id==val.id || links[i].target.id==val.id){
                var temp = links.splice(i,1);
                removedLinks.push(temp[0]);
                obj.update();
            }
        }
    });
    removedNodes.splice(0,removedNodes.length);
}
//determines if node is existing in force.nodes
var isNodeExisting = function(id){
    for (var i in nodes) {
        if (nodes[i]["id"] === id) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//determines if links is existing force.links
var isLinkExisting = function(linkId){
    for (var i in links) {
        if (links[i].linkId === linkId) return true;
    }
}

//adds a link to force.links if link is not existing
this.addLink = function(source,target,linkId){
    if(!isLinkExisting(linkId)){
        links.push({
            'source':findNode(source),
            'target':findNode(target),
            'linkId':linkId
        });
        this.update();
    }  

}


//returns index of switch by taking its id
var findNode = function (id) {
    for (var i in nodes) {
        if (nodes[i]["id"] === id) return nodes[i];
    };
};
var dragstart= function(d) {
        d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}
var dblclick = function(d){
        d3.select(this).classed("fixed",d.fixed=false);
}
var displayHintText = function(d){
        d3.select(this).select('.hintText').text(d.id);
}
var hideHintText = function(d){
        d3.select(this).select('.hintText').text('');
}
//bring nodes to top of links.
this.keepNodesOnTop =function() {

    $(".node").each(function(index) {
        this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
    });

}

var drag = force.drag()
            .on('dragstart',dragstart);

this.update = function(){


    link = vis.selectAll('.link')
              .data(links,function(d){ return d.linkId});

    //remove extra links from SVG
    link.exit().remove();

    //add extra links to SVG
    link.enter()
        .append('line')
        .attr('class','link');

    var node = vis.selectAll('g')
          .data(nodes,function(d){return d.id});

    //remove extra nodes from SVG
    node.exit().remove();

    //add extra nodes to SVG
    var nodeEnter = node.enter()
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('class','node')
                    .on('dblclick', dblclick)
                    .on('mouseover',displayHintText)
                    .on('mouseout',hideHintText)
                    .call(drag);

    //append text element to node group element
    nodeEnter.append('text')
             .attr('class','hintText');

    //append circle to node group element
    nodeEnter.append(function(d){ 

            if(d.type=='circle'){
                return document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",d.type);
            }else if(d.type=='rect'){
                return document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",d.type);
            }

            }).attr('class','node')
              .each(function(d){
                    if(d.type=='circle'){
                        d3.select(this).attr({
                          r:8,
                        });
                    }else if(d.type=='rect'){
                        d3.select(this).attr({
                          width:16,
                          height:16
                        });
                    }
              });


    force.on('tick',function(e){

        node.attr("transform", function (d) {

            if(d.index==0){
                damper = 0.1;
                d.x = d.x + (width/3 - d.x) * (damper + 0.71) * e.alpha;
                d.y = d.y + (height/3 - d.y) * (damper + 0.71) * e.alpha;
            }

            d.x = Math.min(width,Math.max(d.x,10));
            d.y = Math.min(height,Math.max(d.y,10));
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
            });

        link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                 return d.source.x;
            })
            .attr("y1", function (d) {
                return d.source.y;
            })
            .attr("x2", function (d) {
                return d.target.x;
            })
            .attr("y2", function (d) {
                return d.target.y;
            })
            .attr("id",function(d){
                return d.linkId;
            })

    });
    force.gravity(0.06)
        .charge(-1000)
        .linkDistance( function(d) { return 90 } )
        .size([width, height])
        .start();

}

};
```

I am able to get two different force graphs which are dynamic(draggale) but the problem is only links of latest drawn graph are being connected to nodes. Former graph is dynamic but links are static.

I have referred below links, they did'nt work:
[Multiple instances of d3 force layout on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650377/multiple-instances-of-d3-force-layout-on-the-same-page)
[Multiple force-layout graphs with d3 in seperate svg/div's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204352/multiple-force-layout-graphs-with-d3-in-seperate-svg-divs)

Below is a picture of how right side graph is behaving where is left is working properly. I have also given prefix for links as *right* and *left* but of no use.
[image: two force layouts in sigle page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `update()` function I have defined `link` without `var` because of which, it is available globally and is always taking latest graph links. Changing it to `var link` worked fine.